# A question about probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{R}^d)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In Rick Durrett's book *Probability Theory and Examples*, there is a theorem regarding the construction of a probability measure on  $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{R}^d)$.

> **Theorem 1.1.11.** Suppose $F : \mathbb{R}^d \to [0,1]$ satisfies (i) - (iv) given above. Then there is a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{R}^d)$ so that $\mu(A) = \Delta_A F$ for all finite rectangles.
>
> (i) It is nondecreasing, i.e., if $x \le y$ (meaning $x_i \le y_i$ for all $i$) then $F(x) \le F(y)$
>
> (ii) $F$ is right continuous, i.e., $\lim_{y \downarrow x} F(y) = F(x)$ (here $y \downarrow x$ means each $y_i\downarrow x_i$).
>
> (iii) If $x_n \downarrow -\infty$, i.e., each coordinate does, then $F(x_n) \downarrow 0$. If $x_n \uparrow \infty$, i.e., each coordinate does, then $F(x_n) \uparrow 1$.
>
> (iv) $\Delta_A F\ge 0$, where $\Delta_A F = \sum\limits_{v \in V} \text{sgn}(v)F(v)$ and $\text{sgn}(v) = (-1)^{\text{# of } a_i\text{'s in }v}  $
>
> where $A = (a_1,b_1] \times \cdots \times (a_d, b_d]$ and $V = \{a_1, b_1\} \times \cdots \times \{a_d, b_d\}$
>
> For example, when $A = (a_1, b_1] \times (a_2 ,b_2]$, $\Delta_A F = F(b_1, b_2) - F(a_1, b_2) - F_1(b_1, a_2) + F_1(a_1, a_2)$.

Here, I understand everything in the proof except for why this measure is a probability measure. Intuitively, I get it. However, I think we need to show that $F(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_d) = \mu((-\infty, b_1] \times (-\infty, b_2] \times \cdots (-\infty, b_d])$ rigorously. Then we can use (iii) to prove $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d) = 1$. At least, in the proof, there is no explicit mention of why this is a probability measure. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Points (i) to (iv) are the hypotheses of the theorem, right? You don't seem to have quoted the actual proof.

Comment: No, I didn't include any of the proof because the proof is all about the existence and uniqueness of the measure $\mu$ satisfying the conditions (i) - (iv).

Comment: What's $\Delta_A F$? Is $\sum_{v\in V}\mathrm{sgn}(v)F(v)$ the definition? If yes, what is $V$? That expression does not look like it depends on $A$, but I think it should.

Comment: @withgrace1040 Well, no - $\mu$ doesn't satisfy (i)-(iv), $F$ does.

Comment: @JackM Yeah, sorry. $F$ satisfies (i) - (iv). The actual proof is about the uniqueness and existence of $\mu$ with $\mu(A) = \Delta_A F$.

Comment: @Thorgott Sorry for missing some information. I updated it.

Comment: Obviously the intuition here is that $F$ is the cumulative distribution function for $\mu$, so that $F(a)=\mu(x\leq a)$, where $\leq$ is interpreted coordinate-wise. The definition of $\Delta_AF$ is just the formula for the measure of the finite rectangle $A$ given the measures of the infinite rectangles with a vertex at each corner of $A$. So you have the formula for $\mu$ on finite rectangles, and you need to derive the formula for $\mu$ on infinite rectangles. And you already know that $\mu$ is a measure, so we can use that. Is that correct?

Comment: @JackM Intuitively I think $F$ is the cumulative distribution function for $\mu$. However, the only thing we know about the relationship between $\mu$ and $F$ is with finite rectangles. I would like to show for the constructed measure $\mu$, $F(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_d) = \mu((-\infty, b_1] \times \cdots \times (-\infty, b_d])$ as I wrote in the original post. I cannot do it, so I am asking for help.

Comment: @JackM Also I know $\Delta_A F\ge 0$, where $\Delta_A F = \sum\limits_{v \in V} \text{sgn}(v)F(v)$ and $\text{sgn}(v) = (-1)^{\text{# of } a_i\text{'s in }v} $ is derived from the idea of the cumulative distribution. However, I cannot go in reverse. That's the difficulty I am having now.

Comment: I'm not sure these assumptions are strong enough. If we take say $F(x, y)=\frac1{2\pi}\text{arctan}y+\frac12$, this satisfies all of the assumptions, yet $\Delta_AF=0$ for all $A$, so $F$ is certainly not a cumulative probability function.

Comment: @JackM I also think that way, since if that measure $\mu$ exists, then $\mu((-\infty, a]\times (-\infty, b]) = \lim\limits_{n,m \to \infty} \{F(a,b) - F(a-m, b) - F(a, b-n) + F(a-m, b-n)\}$ is supposed to hold. (Even though there are many ways to approach the infinite rectangle, this is one of them.) First, it is clear that $F(a-m, b-n) \to 0$. Also, if $\mu((-\infty, a]\times (-\infty, b])$ are to be the same as $F(a,b)$, $F(a-m, b)$ and $F(a, b-n)$ also have to go to $0$ too, since they are both nonnegative. By the way, thank you for being with me about this problem! :)

Comment: I tracked down the book, and I believe you misquoted it. At least in the first edition, the author has a different point (iii) to yours. In my copy, the assumption is that $F(x)\to1$ as $x\to\infty$, **but**, $F(x)\to0$ as only *one* of the $x_i$, not all, goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: @JackM Thank you for tracking down the book. I checked the book again, which is the fifth edition, and I quoted it right. (You can also download it from his webpage:https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/) Actually, I am not sure what each $x_n \uparrow \infty$ and $x_n \downarrow -\infty$ mean. He used the same notations for the two cases. (I was just able to guess what it means from the picture he added.) Since you said this first edition says it differently, I also look up the 4th edition, which I have, and found out that (iii) is missing. That's a pretty interesting turn of events for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose you've already proven that $\mu$ exists, is unique, and is a measure. Then it remains to prove that $\mu$ is a probability measure. As you point out, it suffices to show that for any $a$:

$$\mu(x\leq a)=\mu\left(\prod_i(-\infty, a_i]\right)=F(a)$$

To show this, express the set $\{x\leq a\}$ as a disjoint union of finite rectangles (for instance by tiling it with cubes), and use the additivity of $\mu$. For example, in two dimensions, we have:

$$\{x\leq a\}=\bigcup_{n,m}(a_1-(m+1), a_1-m]\times(a_2-(n+1),a_2-n]$$

Due to the precise definition of $\Delta_A F$, this sum can be shown to be telescoping and equal to $F(a)$. Applying additivity, the left hand side above becomes

$$\sum_{n, m} \mu\Big(R_{n,m}\Big)=\sum_{n,m} \Delta_{R_{n,m}} F$$

where $R_{n,m}=(a_1-(m+1), a_1-m]\times(a_2-(n+1),a_2-n]$ is the $n,m$-th "tile". When we write out the definition of $\Delta_A F$, the terms of this infinite sum all cancel out except for the initial term $F(a)$, the top right hand corner. Specifically, this sum expands into a sum of terms, each of the form $\pm F(x)$, where $x$ is some grid point of our infinite tiling. These terms can be grouped into groups of four, each group of four corresponding to a given tile $T$, being the expanded form of $\Delta_T F$. Each tile produces the four terms

$$F(t)-F(u)+F(v)-F(w)$$

where $t,u,v$ and $w$ are the corners of that tile, starting from the top right and going clockwise. Therefore:

1. The gridpoint $a$, the top right hand corner of the infinite rectangle, appears only once in this entire sum, with a factor of $+1$, as the top right hand corner of the top right hand tile.
2. Any gridpoint $x$ which appears in the middle of  the infinite rectangle appears four times, once for each of the four tiles of which it is a corner. It bears a factor of $+1$ for the tiles to its top right and bottom left, and a factor of $-1$ for the other two, therefore all of these terms cancel out and the gridpoint in total makes a contribution of $0$ to the infinite sum.
3. Any gridpoint on the right hand side of the infinite rectangle appears twice, once with a factor of $-1$ and once with a factor of $+1$, and therefore also drops out of the sum.
4. Analogously for gridpoints on the top of the rectangle.

To show this formally of course would be tedious, especially in $n$ dimensions, but could be done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I also thought about this. However, the tricky part for me is $-\infty$ part. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$,  $\mu(\{x \le a, y \le b\}) = \lim\limits_{m,n \to \infty}  \{F(a,b) - F(a-m, b) - F(a, b-n) + F(a-m, b-n)\}$. How can I show $F(a-m, b) \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ and $F(a, b-n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? Because of $(iii)$, I know $F(a-m, b-n) \to 0$ as $m$, $n \to \infty$.

Comment: What you're suggesting if different to what I wrote. You're talking about covering an infinite rectangle with a larger and larger rectangle, rather than tiling it with infinitely many rectangles. The approach you're describing seems more difficult to me.

Comment: By tiling, you mean adding putting $1 \times 1$ tiles to the body? If so, when you are done with $m \times n$ tiles, then you will get a larger rectangle. 

I might not understand your approach well. Could you elaborate on why $\mu (\bigcup\limits_{n,m} (a- (m+1), a-m] \times (a- (n+1), a-n] ) = F(a)$. I still don't see why rigorously.

Comment: That equation is what you need to show. The union on the left hand side is equal, as a set, to the set $\{x\leq a\}$ - the big infinite rectangle. The fact that its measure is equal to $F(a)$ ($a$ is the top right corner of the infinite rectangle) is what you need to prove. To do so, what I suggest is to notice that measure is equal to the sum of the measures of the infinitely many "tiles", apply the formula given by your assumptions to calculate those measures, and notice that the sum is telescoping.

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but 'are you kidding me?' I know the left side is the infinite rectangle. I have been asking you how I could show the equality holds. Can you do that or is it only your intuition? My question has always been about the equality. Would you just give me a solid way of showing the proof, not only saying telescoping?

Comment: @withgrace1040 I detailed the telescoping argument.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your effort to help me understand it. However, I have a question about your method. For example, consider this sequence $a_n = -n + (n+1)$. and its infinite sum. $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + = (-1+2)+(-2+3) \cdots $. During the process, every term except for the first term $-1$ is canceled. However, we cannot say that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = -1$. It rather diverges to $\infty$. Is there any difference between this example and your approach? Please let me now if I have a misunderstanding.

Comment: You're right, there is an additional technical difficulty here. What we need to show is that the value of our infinite sum does not change under permutations of its terms. Showing that this is the case may end up being as difficult or more as the approach that you suggested earlier, so maybe my answer isn't as clever as I thought.