# Distribution Function for Beginners

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know distributions do not necessarily have density, ie PDF function. My understanding is that, this lack of density comes from either from some sort of non-differentiability on their support set, or that a superset of their support is considered as the domain.

No matter if the above understanding is exactly correct or roughly or not, one can ask a similar question about CDF.

- Do all distributions have distribution function (CDF)?
- What if we constrain them to their support?
- Is it true that distribution can have CDF, but not a PDF?

Edit:

- What if data is multi-variate as opposed to real?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of a random variable $X$ is characterized by the function $P(X\in S)$ on sets. In particular, any real variable $X$ has a CDF $P(X\le x)$. Its derivative if it exists is the PDF, but the derivative may not exist, in which case there is no PDF. For example, [discrete random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Discrete_random_variable) have [PMFs (probability mass functions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) instead. With the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) this can be manipulated as a density, viz. $\sum_kP(X=k)\delta(x-k)$. However, like the delta itself, the result is a measure rather than a true function.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's consider distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ only. In this case a distribution is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. In particular, it is a [Borel measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure) on $\mathbb{R}$.

(1) If $P$ is a (probability) distribution, there always exists a CDF $F$ s.t. $F(b)-F(a)=P((b,a])$. The converse is also true (see, e.g, Theorem 1.16 in Folland's Real Analysis).

(2) $P$ has a density function only if $P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. There are many cases violating this condition, e.g. $P(A)=1_{\{0\}}(A)$.

Comment: What is the generalization of (1) for multi-variate case?

Comment: @user25004 See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529486/a-question-about-probability-measure-on-mathbbrd-mathcalrd) question.

Comment: @ d.k.o. The question you mention does mention that every F with some properties is a cdf, but does not mention if every probability measure has some cdf.

Comment: @user25004 You're right. However, the other direction is simple: define $F(x):=P((-\infty,x])$. It is not hard to see that $F$ is a cdf.